# Why does this Largest Prime Factor of a given number in python algorithm work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, primes, prime-factoring

I am unable to understand the following block of code which I came across this site itself. It creates a function to find out the largest prime factor of a given number. It is given below:

```
def prime_factors(n):
"""Returns all the prime factors of a positive integer"""
factors = []
d = 2
while n > 1:
    while n % d == 0:
        factors.append(d)
        n /= d
    d = d + 1

return factors
pfs = prime_factors(1000)
largest_prime_factor = max(pfs) # The largest element in the prime
```

My doubt is that the function `prime_factors(n)` would return the **factors** of `n` and not the **prime factors**, since the while loop is only checking if `d` is a factor of `n` and not if it is also a prime as it should be.

Please point out if I'm wrong and also the reasoning behind your logic. Furthermore, if I'm correct, then kindly provide a suitable block of code and the logic behind it in simple terms. Try to keep the code as simple as possible.

Comment: Here's how I would approach this problem. Step 1: I'd run the program with examples, and see if it produces factors or prime factors. Step 2: when I discover my guess is wrong (and the program does work as advertised), I'd run through the program myself with small numbers (n=4, n=6, n=18 might be interesting ones) and see what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

Note that in the inner loop, `n` is divided by `d` while iteration.

```
while n % d == 0:
    factors.append(d)
    n /= d
```

That means, after each iteration, it's impossible for the new value of `n` to be divisible by `d` any more.

Take an example, let's say `n = 3000`, it has a factor `15` that isn't a prime number. However, because `n` is passed by `d = 3` and `d = 5` first, by the time `d` reaches `15`, `n` would have been a number that's neither divisible by `3` nor `5`, so the non-prime factor `15` would not pass `n % d == 0` now.

Comment: Thanks so much! Also, instead of writing "n > 1", couldn't we write "d <= n" to simplify things?

Answer (score 2):

This function is correct, pay attention to the second while block. It will continuously divide the given number by the `d` variable, when the result of the division has a remainder, it will leave this block and increment `d` by one, then it will run again.

Having that in mind, this function will divide the number by 2 as many times it can without leaving a remainder, then it will move to the next number that doesn't leave remainders. In the end the result will only contain prime numbers.

It'll go like this:

```
def prime_factors(n):
   factors = []
   d=2
   while n > 1:
     while n % d == 0:
       factors.append(d)
       n /= d
     d += 1
   return factors

print(prime_factors(1000)) # will print [2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5]
```